# get value from the url

Tags: javascript, url

I have a url in the format`http://localhost:8080/testURL/location/#/old/Ds~1016`,

The value 1016 will change based on the page selected.. is it possible in javascript to get the number 1016 part from url(based on page selected)???

Ive tried the function

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
var regex = new RegExp(regexS);

var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
if (results == null)
    return "";
else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: Is it always at the end of the URL?

Comment: Is it always 4 characters or will that change?

Comment: `window.location.hash.split('~')[1]`

Comment: Even if not, you don't need to use Regex. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try it this way

```
window.location.href.split('~').pop(-1)
```

that should give you `"1016"`

Although the following would be better

```
window.location.href.split('/').pop(-1).split('~').pop(-1)
```

to make sure it is the last "/" element you are splitting

**UPDATE**

I always prefer using split() if it is for a single condition because the code is more understandable even though regex give better performance in the longer run. You can check the performance of regex vs split [here](http://jsperf.com/string-match-vs-string-split/6)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
regex = new RegExp("[0-9]*$");
regex.exec(window.location.hash);
```

To get the number, just use `regex.exec(window.location.hash)[0]`, and then you may need to check whether it is 4 digits width.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use the built-in `window.location`. And without `regex` you can do:

```
a = "http://localhost:8080/testURL/location/#/old/Ds~1016";
a.substring(a.indexOf("~")+1); // 1016
```

Or in a simpler way, you can use this:

```
window.location.hash.split('~')[1]
```

#### You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DqzQF/

Feel free to try out all the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.hash.split('~')[1]`

**Explanation:**

We first grab the hash i.e. `#/old/Ds~1016`
by `window.location.hash`

Now, we `split` the hash with `~` (I assume that comes only one time in url)

split returns an array with `Ds` at `0th` index and `1016` at `1st` index.

So, finally

```
window.location.hash.split('~')[1] returns `1016`
```